# launch an angularjs app from non base url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to solve a simple problem related to single page apps and angularjs in particular.  There surely must be an easy way to do this that I am somehow missing.

Start by considering how a non single page app works.  Let's say I have an index.html file in the root and a subfolder called other with other.html inside it.   If  I launch mysite.com/ in the browser, it will serve up index.html by default and everything works fine.  If I launch mysite.com/other/other.html it will also work fine because other.html is a real file and includes all of the supporting resource files etc.

Now consider a single page angular app, let's say using ui-router. I create a route:  state=other, url=/other   and template=other/other.html with a controller attached

If I launch mysite.com.  It loads the angular index.html file and I get the home page as expected.  I can then go to the browser and type mysite.com/#/other and it will correctly load the other.html page as expected

The problem comes when I want to launch the app directly into mysite.com/other.  The first problem I will encounter is a 404 because even if there is a directory other, there is no index.html there and the other.html file is only a template anyway so wouldn't load the resources needed to run the app.

Somehow the server needs to know that for an angular app, any url without a resource file name at the end it must load index.html and let the angular router provide the actual page.

I even tried this with the server, having it return index.html when you request the url mysite.com/other.  This does succeed in loading the angular app but to my surprise, mysite.com/other now shows mysite.com/other#/ in the url. In other words, it now treats other as part of the base url so I have to type /other again (i.e. mysite.com/other#/other)  to get it to show the other page.

I have tried various experiments using the base tag and html5mode but am still not able to find a suitable solution.

Comment: in short what r u trying to accomplish here?  to redirect mysite.com/other to mysite.com/#/other ?

Comment: In a sense yes.  I want the user to be able to save a link mysite.com/other and then launch the app to that page just like you can with most websites.

Comment: try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have figured out a solution.  I set base url to / and turn on html5mode.  I also have to configure the server to return index.html for any request with no file at the end (i.e. no extension)